# Should I have said something when I realized I have a personal connection to one of the interviewers?

Tags: interviewing, conflict-of-interest

I just did an interview for a job I really want. Only problem is one of the interviewers was my ex's new fiancée. I was unaware until she introduced herself. She knew beforehand as she had the list of interviews in advance. I believe she has bad feelings for me. I still want the job because I wouldn't be working with her at all.

I haven't gotten a call if I got it or not, but I'm wondering if I should've said something before starting the interview or if I even have a leg to stand on? I had 3 interviewers total.

Comment: Were none of you aware of this before the interview?

Comment: Why do you think your ex's new fiancée would have any bad feelings towards you?

Comment: @brhans Would specifics about the relationships change the answer? EDIT: Clarification on how much this person dislikes OP is important but I don't know if we need to know exactly why.

Comment: @BSMP - ok, sure - specifics are not necessary to answer the question. So to rephrase then - Do you have any reasonable grounds to believe that your ex's new fiancée would have any bad feelings towards you?

Comment: Irrespective of the interview, is this role still one you want in light of this info. Will working with your ex's fiancee present a challenge for you within the organization. Are they in a position of authority of the role and would you be able to be effective.

Comment: I was unaware until she introduced her self. She knew before hand as she had the list of interviews on advance. Yes, I believe she has bad feelings for me. Yes I still want the job because I wouldn't be working with her at all.

Comment: To raise a point which I don’t think has been mentioned, assuming the interviewer recognised you, it’s very unprofessional that they didn’t mention this themself. If I were put in that situation I’d recuse myself, or at least make sure all the team knew of it in advance.

Comment: @NeilTarrant We don't actually know that the interviewer didn't tell their co-workers in advance, just that they didn't say anything in the interview. Assuming OP is right that she would have noticed their name in the list and recognized it, she might have told everyone else. Maybe she assumed he also already knew she'd be there?

Comment: @BSMP - the interviewer is in a position of power in any job interview. It is their duty to ensure that the interviewee feels comfortable. They should have brought it up in the interview - either as a question "[OP], as you know [explanation of relationship] ... do you feel comfortable to continue?" or as a statement - "[OP],  I have informed the other members of this panel that [explanation of relationship]."

Comment: _"She knew before hand as she had the list of interviews on advance."_ is not proof that she realized specifically who you were. It may have been someone else with the same name; or she may simply not have really paid attention to the list of names (I'll admit that I tend not to remember many names of people whose CV I've seen but not interviewed yet). I'm not saying that she didn't recognize you; I'm saying that you can't know for a fact whether she did or not, unless you have a really unique name or live in a small community.

Comment: We live in a small town.... She knew...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I agree with the others that it's too late now - to answer the actual question asked, yes I think it would have been best for you to have acknowledged the connection as soon as you realized. When introduced in the interview you should have said something like:

> I think I know you from somewhere.

Answer (score 17):

> I'm looking for advice I guess.

Ignore it. If everyone behaves professionally, that it will have no impact. If there is strong emotional interference, there is nothing you can do about it.

Just keep it professional yourself.

Answer (score 6):

If you feel that this specific interviewer would have been unable to provide an unbiased assessment of your fit for the role then yes you should have spoken up immediately.

At this point you just need to wait for their response and hope for the best.

Answer (score -1):

Worst case: Your ex told her new fiancé things about you that are extremely unflattering / would make me not want to employ you. These things might be true or false. Whether he is part of the interview or not, the company will learn about it.

If all he knows about you is in the normal range of human then there should be no problem.